# Is this possible to draw a full circle involing cot or tan?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, draw

I have a code like this to draw multiple points into a circle

```
    var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
    var centerX = 500;
    var centerY = 500;
    cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

    var increment = 1/100;       
    var distance = 100;

    for( theta=0;theta <100; theta++) {      
      var newX = centerX +distance *Math.cos(theta*2*Math.PI*increment); 
      var newY = centerY +distance *Math.sin(theta*2*Math.PI*increment); 
      cxt.fillText("0",newX, newY);
    }
    cxt.stroke();
```

Outcome:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyHIy.png)

I try to rewote the code with `tan` & `cot (1/tan)`but what i get usually an eclipse or oval. Can we use these function to make a perfect circle out of given points?

Comment: Which function did you use to get newx and newy from tan and cotan?

Comment: just Math.tan for tan & 1/Math.tan for cotan, basic math

Comment: Why do you want to use tan or cot ? These functions are singular.

Comment: just try new thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible - the `tan` is enough ([formulas here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Sum_and_difference_formulas))

```js
var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
var centerX = 100;
var centerY = 100;
cxt.moveTo(centerX, centerY);

var increment = 1 / 50;
var distance = 90;

for (let theta = 0; theta < 100; theta++) {
  var t = Math.tan(theta * Math.PI * increment);
  var newX = centerX + distance * (1 - t*t)/(1 + t*t);
  var newY = centerY + distance * 2 * t/(1 + t*t);
  cxt.fillText("0", newX, newY);
}
cxt.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Comment: if you want to use cot just change t to `var t=1/cot(theta * Math.PI * increment)` (and ofcourse provide `cot` function because standard JS Math not contains it)